# Metro app- Custom listbox/listview

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, listview, listbox, microsoft-metro

I have developed an app for WP7, there creation and usage of a custom listbox is through a new class.

Once the elements such as Textbox is declared in the CustomListBox.xaml, it can be used in MainPage.cs.

Here goes the CustomListBox.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.CustListbox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="gradient.jpeg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <TextBlock Height="56"  Margin="160,19,0,75" Name="textBlock1" Text="" Width="293"  FontStyle="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                           TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Verdana"/>

        <Image Height="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,19,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
        <TextBlock Height="61"  Margin="160,81,0,8" Name="textBlock2" Text="" Width="293"  FontStyle="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                           TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the way I use that in my MainPage.cs is

```
private void readSQLCE()
        {
            db = new MyDataContext("isostore:/aa.sdf");

            //IntroductionTable
            var IT_Q = from b in db.IT where b.IT_id < 8 select b;
            List<IntroductionTable> l_It = IT_Q.ToList();

            try
            {
                foreach (IntroductionTable itt in l_It)
                {
                    //Instance for list items
                    CustListbox clb = new CustListbox();
                    blob = itt.IT_Image;
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(blob);
                    WriteableBitmap bimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);
                    clb.textBlock1.Text = itt.IT_intro;
                    clb.image1.Source = bimg;
                    MyListBox.Items.Add(clb);
                    //addingcts();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }



        }
```

The following would be the listbox's implementation MainPage.xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="-4,6,-12,12" SelectionChanged="MyListBox_SelectionChanged">

            </ListBox>
```

I would like to know if in the metro apps, same procedure could be followed?

I tried customising using the same approach, but failed. Am I supposed to follow a different approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, post here some code samples, so I can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store / Metro apps share the same core concepts of how you assemble the UI as WP7. You can create user controls or custom controls, both of which can be re-used in the XAML for your pages.

Basically, you've done something wrong! You'll have to supply more detail to get a proper answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I have checked if something went wrong. But it wasn't.. Will check again.